# What part of speech is "Surrounded" in this sentence please?

Tags: parts-of-speech, object-complements

My dream job is to run my own communication business surrounded by talented people.

I see "my dream job" (Subject) "is" (verb) "To run my own comms company" (Subject complement)... But "surrounded" is giving me some problems. It looks like an object complement, but I am unsure if we can use an OC after the object of a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

> My dream job is to run my own communication business surrounded by talented people.

The example is fine.

"surrounded by talented people" is a subbordinate past-participial clause modifying business.  It is similar to the relative clause "that is surrounded by talented people".

"surrounded" is a past-partiple verb.

Answer (score 0):

="with  talented people all around me"

= 'working with  talented people'

It's the subject surrounded by the  talented people-
'while I am surrounded by  talented people'

The sentence is perfectly correct, idiomatic  and understandable.
It's an adverb, modifying "job"